# Deep linking opens only in browser

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I am using deep linking in android application.

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

but when intent is fire there the option of app is show. i need only browser option will be show from deep link.

Please help!

Comment: The feature of deep links is to allow http or other links to open your app. If you want the browser to open always, do not add the above code snippet then all your links will by default open on Chrome browser